# Can't type in QlineEdit if the keyPressEvent is on

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am having a problem with the QLineEdit, if i enable the keyPressEvent in the code then i am not able to type anything in the QLineEdit.

```
class SearchBox(gui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SearchBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Explorer")
        self.setGeometry(500,500,400,40)
        font = gui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.setFont(font)

    # if i disable this function then it works..
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == core.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
        if event.key() == core.Qt.Key_Enter:
            print self.text()
            self.close()
```

can someone please help me with this..
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't call the `keyPressEvent` of the base class how is it supposed to know that some key was pressed?

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == core.Qt.Key_Escape:
        self.close()
    if event.key() == core.Qt.Key_Enter:
        print self.text()
        self.close()
    else:
        super(SearchBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

This is also mentioned in the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent):

> If you reimplement this handler, it is very important that you call
>   the base class implementation if you do not act upon the key.